# Rails, Moment, and Timezones (abbreviations + offsets)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, momentjs

I am creating a Rails API that will be consumed by a Javascript framework. Time display and manipulation will be controlled with MomentJS. It is important for the front-end to be able to display the dates along with the time zone abbreviations (e.g. `1/1/2010 11:00 PST`).

From what I understand, an offset (e.g. `-0700`) is not enough to determine the actual timezone, and the timezone abbreviations aren't always unique.

I can think of only two options to solve this:

1. Return all times in UTC and have an extra field for each time specifying the timezone (e.g. `{ pick_up: "17-06-08T18:59:21.215Z", pick_up_tz: 'America/New_York' }` (or `pick_up_tz: 'PST'`)
2. Use a non-standard datetime format, something that includes both the timezone abbreviation and the offset (e.g. `{ pick_up: "17/09/06 13:34:00 CDT -05:00"`)

Are these reasonable solutions or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use a non-standard datetime format

Never do this. An API should always return time in [ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html).

> Return all times in UTC and have an extra field for each time specifying the timezone

You are correct that an offset is insufficient to identify time zone, so you do need to include that in the API response, ideally as an [IANA time zone](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

Whether you convert to UTC or include an offset is a matter of preference; `2017-06-08T18:59:21.215Z` and `2017-06-08T11:59:21.215-0700` mean the same time, regardless of the time zone you convert to for display. Including the offset can be useful to identify if the stored offset is different from the time zone, as you might only show the time zone qualifier if the offset is different.